# squirrel sql installation

Tags: windows, db2, squirrel-sql

I have a question regarding SQL Squirrel installation. Someone at work told me that we can use sql squirrel already packaged as java executable. I am not sure what he means and what i need to do at my end to get SQL Squirrel going.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have a JRE (Java runtime environment) installed on your Windows, then you can run Squirrel SQL directly as a Java application.

Comment: Would i need to download the jar file for SQL Squirrel in that scenario?

Comment: Yes, perhaps you would have to.  Just download whatever they say for Java.